# Getting errors when patching a npm package

Tags: patch, yarnpkg-v2

when I patch a dependency like this:

`package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": 
    "react-native-webview": "patch:react-native-webview@11.0.3#scripts/patches/react-native-webview+11.0.3.patch",
    ...
```

`patches/react-native-webview+11.0.3.patch`:

```
diff --git a/apple/RNCWebView.m b/apple/RNCWebView.m
index ff9ff9e0..dfea91a8 100644
--- a/apple/RNCWebView.m
+++ b/apple/RNCWebView.m
@@ -194,12 +194,18 @@ - (void)dealloc
...
```

everything works fine when I install things locally using `yarn` or `yarn install`. The patch gets applied, and there are no errors.

However, when things go into CI, I get an error like the following:

```
**ERROR** Failed to apply patch for package react-native-webview at path
  
    node_modules/react-native-webview

  This error was caused because patch-package cannot apply the following patch file:

    patches/react-native-webview+11.0.3.patch

  Try removing node_modules and trying again. If that doesn't work, maybe there was
  an accidental change made to the patch file? Try recreating it by manually
  editing the appropriate files and running:
  
    patch-package react-native-webview
  
  If that doesn't work, then it's a bug in patch-package, so please submit a bug
  report. Thanks!

    https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/issues
```

Things don't get better if I change the patch to use paths like `a/node_modules/react-native-webview/apple/RNCWebView.m`. I then get an error like

```
➤ YN0001: │ Error: react-native-webview@patch:react-native-webview@npm%3A11.0.3#../../scripts/patches/react-native-webview+11.0.3.patch::version=11.0.3&hash=d13297&locator=proj-core%40workspace%3Alib%2Fproj-core: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/node_modules/react-native-webview/node_modules/react-native-webview/apple/RNCWebView.m'
    at rn (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:172:9625)
    at kn (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:172:9889)
    at Qr.resolveFilename (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:21594)
    at Qr.resolveFilename (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:21498)
    at Qr.resolveFilename (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:21498)
    at Qr.lstatSync (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:18712)
    at Qr.lstatPromise (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:18671)
    at yt.lstatPromise (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:177:34701)
    at Zu (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:578:7908)
    at YB (/home/user/dev/proj-client/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.0.cjs:580:184)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using two different tools to patch the npm package, and using a different one locally than in CI:

- [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) as a post-install script (if you check the "postinstall" entry in your package.json, you'll see something like `patch-package --patch-dir ./scripts/patches`)
- yarn's built-in package patching thing, which uses `patch:` in package.json.

However, they work differently:

| patch-package | yarn's `patch:` |
| --- | --- |
| applies the patch from the project root, so you need to include `node_modules/package-name` in the diff. | applies the patch from the package install directory, so you don't need to do that |
| requires that the patch be named `package-name+version.patch` | doesn't require any specific naming |

The solution here is to pick one, and to change the patch to work with that system. So, for example, if you rename the file to remove the `+version`, you'll be able to move forward using just yarn's `patch:`.

Answer (score 2):

I make downgrade:

```
"patch-package": "^5.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone still looks up for this issue.

My issue was the difference of **resolved** version in `yarn.lock`.

I had a different `package.json` versions in my case, and i copied the code and it didn't work because the yarn.lock was already generated.
I just copied over the old yarn file and it worked perfectly.

For instance, my yarn.lock looked like this
[image]

I changed it to match the correct version
[image]